# A question about integration of a orthogonal function

Tags: calculus, integration, cauchy-principal-value

I have trouble figure out this orthogonal integration:
$$
\Psi _{1}=sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a}),\Psi _{2}=cos(\frac{n\pi x}{a})
$$
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty}sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})cos(\frac{n\pi x}{a})dx
$$
$$\Psi _{1}$$ and $$\Psi _{2}$$ are orthogonals.
This problem is not very complicated, I just need to prove
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty}sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})cos(\frac{n\pi x}{a})dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty}sin\frac{2n\pi x}{a}dx=0
$$
Here is why the problem bothers me. If the statement is a true statement, that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}sinkxdx=0
$$
has to be true.However, the improper integral,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}sinkxdx
$$
is divergent.
This is contradicted to the statement. So how should I understand this. And we 
know the Cauchy principal which shows that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}sinkxdx=\lim_{A \to +\infty}\int_{-A}^{+A}sinkxdx=0
$$
So how can I know when I can use the Cauchy principal to solve problems?
Or is this principal helpful to understand this question?

Comment: the functions you have aren't orthogonal on an infinite interval. The fact it doesn't converge clues you in. They're only orthogonal from $-a$ to $a$

Comment: @RHowe But then the answer to the first integration doesn’t exist because it is not convergent. However, the book where I read this problem tells me the answer should be “0” without further explanation. Then I am confused and eager to know why and whether the Cauchy principal will help to get the correct answer.

Comment: right, you should probably consider how $\Psi_{1}, \Psi_{2}$ actually arose. Like what equation gave way to them.